# Compatablity issue for window.showModalDialog() in safari browser of Ipad

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, ipad, safari

I am running my asp.net application on safari in Ipad,I want to disable parent window when any pop up window is opened.
For this I was using..

```
window.showModalDialog("Questions.aspx?store=" + Store + "&auditDate=" + AuditDate + "&section=" + SectionId, "", "dialogHeight:750px; dialogWidth:950px;center:yes;edge:raised; Scroll:Yes; ");
```

But showModalDialog() method was not working in safari Browser in Ipad,so I am using window.open() function.But functionality of showModalDialog() has been lost.

Please let me , How to disable parent window when Pop window is opened , and let me know any alternative way to achieve this functionality without using showModalDialog() Method , to work in all Browser without compatiblity issues with Browser.

Answer (score -1):

window.showModalDialog is specific only to IE. You should consider using JQuery UI for your modal dialogs [Jquery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: jQuery UI modal dialogs are divs simulating modal dialogs. They do not block the browser thread the way real modals do, which may be necessary if attempting to prolong something like a beforeunload event while doing some kind of cleanip.